# Problems with IsInRole - customRoleProvider

Tags: c#, silverlight, roleprovider

I implemented a custom RoleProvider with custom Authentication over the weekend. Using the Silverlight Business Template, I was able to put a [RequiresRole("Admin")] attribute on a service request:

```
[RequiresRole("Admin")]
public IQueryable<P_BUDGET> GetBudgets()
{
    return this.ObjectContext.P_BUDGET;
}
```

This worked like a charm. I used the following code

I then dropped in Kyle McClellans authorization library. If I set a "RequiresRole" attribute on a HyperlinkButton in my XAML (s:Authorization.RequiresRole="Admin"), it hides the button successfully on app load. When I login, I expected it to identify the "Admin" role that my test user is in, eventually changing the visibility of that HLB to true. However, when I step through the code, I get into my App.Web.g.cs file, and it has this function:

```
public bool IsInRole(string role)
    {
        if ((this.Roles == null))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return global::System.Linq.Enumerable.Contains(this.Roles, role);
    }
```

In the above code, this.Roles is null. What am I missing here? The first code block uses the "GetRolesForUser" method, which I've overridden, and returns a list of roles from a View I have in my db. The second used the IsInRole, which I have read is not something you should modify.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: When does this.Roles get populated? If it never does, it'll always be null.

Comment: I don't know how to populate this.Roles. The answer below might do the trick but I'm not sure. I've been trying to populate that for days now. I thought that's what I was setting in my custom role manager with getrolesforuser, when I went out and go the roles from db and returned an array of strings per the method signature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answers guys, but I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584078/how-to-override-silvelright-4-ria-service-authenticationservice-user-isinrole) by a comment made by Kyle McClellan in his own answer. I was already overriding GetAuthenticatedUser, part of which included getting my roles from the db. Quite simply, I had to put user.Roles = roles, where roles is a list of the roles returned from my db View.

Answer (score 1):

Your custom role provider should be responsible for generating the list of roles from your database or verifying if the user is in a role via a database call

Take a look at this sample code from microsoft: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.isuserinrole.aspx

Comment: I guess my comment didn't save. Where do I override the isinrole?

Answer (score 0):

i've implemented my custon role provider, you need to create the roles in the global.asax, int Application_Start method. I've something like this:

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Roles.ApplicationName = "MyAppName";

    if (!Roles.RoleExists("admin"))
        Roles.CreateRole("admin");

    if (!Roles.RoleExists("operator"))
        Roles.CreateRole("operator");

    if (!Roles.RoleExists("user"))
        Roles.CreateRole("user");
}
```

Good luck.

Comment: I am concerned by the default behavior of those functions. I dont have a roles db of the same schema. I'm simply calling a view in my entity data model to get roles, and I'm not sure how that ties in with the above.

Answer (score 0):

`Roles` in this case is a property of the `UserBase` class inherited by the `User` class that's defined in the supporting web project (`Models/User` folder). By default, this uses the Forms Authentication mecanism and data about users, profiles, "roles", etc. are stored in a local database (in the `App_Data` folder). For this to work, I suggest that you override this property to return the specific roles you need, and you should also set Forms Authentication to use your own user data.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Using forms auth already. I also have already tried to override the Roles prop inside of my user.cs file, but got an error that roles was not overrideable since it's not declared as virtual, overrideable, etc...

Comment: Well, I guess you could always have your own implementation of `User` that implements `IUser` (and maybe `IPrincipal` and `IIdentity` which are implemented by `UserBase` used by the default `User` class)